# using Requests for a get request instead of curl

Tags: python, curl

I'm trying to play with Petfinder's API, which recommends using curl to get a token key instead of requests. How can I convert their recommended curl code into Requests specific language that works? THe documentations is listed here https://www.petfinder.com/developers/v2/docs/#using-the-api

Recommended curl code:

```
curl -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={CLIENT-ID}&client_secret={CLIENT-SECRET}" https://api.petfinder.com/v2/oauth2/token
```

I tried the below (iterating through combos of CLIENT-ID and CLIENT-SECRET, but to no success.

```
import requests

params = {params = {'CLIENT-ID': XXXXXXXXX,
'CLIENT-SECRET': XXXXXXXX}
}


r = requests.get('https://api.petfinder.com/v2/oauth2/token', params = params)
```

And I received an error 401 message that indicates that my authorization isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
import requests
client_id = ""
client_pass = ""
data = {"grant_type":"client_credentials"}
api_url = "https://api.petfinder.com/v2/oauth2/token"
r = requests.post(api_url,data=data,auth=(client_id,client_pass))
r = r.json()
```

Comment: That works! Why do you use requests.post instead of request.get?

Comment: In get request we can't send body. Please accept my answer if working